# Complex JSON using JSON_MODIFY without nested arrays or escape characters (WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I am using `JSON_MODIFY` to build complex JSON. Moving from MySQL I am struggling with the JSON functions provided by SQL Server. The issue I'm having is that SQL Server seems to construct all JSON objects in an array. There is the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` mechanism, which seems like it should do what I want, however; there are two undesirable consequences.

1. It only returns one result depending on how it is used
2. The result is a single string with escape characters

I have constructed a simple query which illustrates my needs and the issue.

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
    JSON_QUERY('{"definitions": {"id": "INT", "name": "VARCHAR(23)"}}'),
    'append $.data',
    (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS id, '123abc' AS "name" UNION
            SELECT 2 AS id, '234bcd' AS "name"
        ) AS "data"
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER 
    ) 
) AS "data";
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
{
   "definitions":{
      "id":"INT",
      "name":"VARCHAR(23)"
   },
   "data":[
      "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"123abc\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"234bcd\"}"
   ]
}
```

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
    JSON_QUERY('{"definitions": {"id": "INT", "name": "VARCHAR(23)"}}'),
    'append $.data',
    (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS id, '123abc' AS "name" UNION
            SELECT 2 AS id, '234bcd' AS "name"
        ) AS "data"
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) 
) AS "data";
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
{
   "definitions":{
      "id":"INT",
      "name":"VARCHAR(23)"
   },
   "data":[
      [
         {"id":1, "name":"123abc"},
         {"id":2, "name":"234bcd"}
      ]
   ]
}
```

- **QUERY 1**
  The `data` object is an array (which is expected), but the problem is what is in the array... A single string with escape characters.
- **QUERY 2**
  The `data` object is an array, which contains an array. In order to access the actual array of data, I would use something like `for each obj in data[0]...`. The problem this poses is, for anyone consuming the JSON object, I would have to tell ***them***:

> "In this particular object the `data` element is an array of
> arrays--You'll want to use the **first** and only the **first**
> element to access the actual array of data."

I've naively tried many different combinations of `JSON_MODIFY`, `JSON_QUERY`, and `CONCAT` to no avail. How can I properly use `JSON_MODIFY` to get the following output, without the double array in `data`?

```
{
   "definitions":{
      "id":"INT",
      "name":"VARCHAR(23)"
   },
   "data":[
     {"id":1, "name":"123abc"},
     {"id":2, "name":"234bcd"}
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking this by trying to `JSON_MODIFY` an existing object.

Construct the `definitions` and `data` properties that you need, inside a subquery if necessary.

Then use `FOR JSON` a second time to get the outer object.

```sql
SELECT 
    definitions = JSON_QUERY('{"id": "INT", "name": "VARCHAR(23)"}'),
    data = 
    (
        SELECT id, name
        FROM (VALUES
            (1, '123abc'),
            (2, '234bcd')
        ) v(id, name)
        FOR JSON PATH
    )
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/129658)

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I found the solution.

1. Removed the `append` keyword from the **path** parameter in the `JSON_MODIFY` statement
2. Removed the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` parameter from the `FOR JSON` statement.

Now the results are as expected and I don't need to explain to any consumers to "Just use data[0]"

**The Query**

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
    JSON_QUERY('{"definitions": {"id": "INT", "name": "VARCHAR(23)"}}'),
    '$.data',
    (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS id, '123abc' AS "name" UNION
            SELECT 2 AS id, '234bcd' AS "name"
        ) AS "data"
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) 
) AS "data";
```

**Produces the following output**

```
{
   "definitions":{
      "id":"INT",
      "name":"VARCHAR(23)"
   },
   "data":[
     {"id":1, "name":"123abc"},
     {"id":2, "name":"234bcd"}
   ]
}
```